# Google drive api folder list files

Tags: google-drive-api

Suddenly getting files in public folder on google drive doesnt seem to get any results back.

I havent changed any code, this is the url I am using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='FOLDER_ID'+in+parents&pageSize=1000&key=API_KEY
```

My api key works. Has anything changed?

when I try in api explorer:  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

I only input q parameter (my folder id), I get:

> {
> "error": {
> "errors": [
> {
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "invalid",
> "message": "Invalid Value",
> "locationType": "parameter",
> "location": "q"
> }
> ],
> "code": 400,
> "message": "Invalid Value"
> }
> }

My folder id is correct.

---

edit: I have created a new folder and added some files inside and now its working, but its still does not work with old folders. Not sure why. If this was the case that files were maybe deleted from my drive, (but still show in folder for some reason?) then it might explain the results.

Comment: You may want to cross post this to the [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566261) if you are sure that you have not changed anything

Comment: I havent changed anything, but its easy to test for anybody, just input your folder id and api key in url above and open in browser.

Comment: If its a bug in the api we cant help you with that you need to submit an issue with the team at google

Comment: Not able to reproduce this with this URL as long as the quotes are around the q parameter. Can you double check your folder ID

Comment: Yes, I have quotes.  I cant get it working with any folder id. This is one of my folder id 0ByzcNpNrQNpWbjJGY19NSFF0R3M and its public, can you see the files?

Comment: I can't see the files, but I get a 200 response `{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": []
}`. #